# Explicit Event Listener injection to webview

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview, addeventlistener

```
static func getWebKitView(uiController : ViewController, uiView : UIView, handlerName : String) -> WKWebView {
    let controller  = WKUserContentController()
    controller.add(uiController, name: handlerName)

    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    config.userContentController = controller

    let scriptSource = """
        document.addEventListener('touchstart', function() { console.log('touchstart from Swift') })
        """
    let script = WKUserScript(source: scriptSource, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
    controller.addUserScript(script)

    let webKitView = WKWebView(frame: .init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: uiView.frame.width, height: uiView.frame.height), configuration: config)
    webKitView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
    webKitView.scrollView.contentSize = uiView.frame.size
    // webKitView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    return webKitView
}
```

> How does adding that `scriptSource` help?

I have made a carousel in my javascript app. When I tried to swipe images in it. I could only move to 2nd image and further swiping didnot work. But when I added the `scriptSource` that issue resolved.

I want to know what has actually happened when I added that piece of code and why without that my js code was not listening to `touchmove` event.

I tried changing this script

```
let scriptSource = """
        document.addEventListener('touchstart', function() { console.log('touchstart from Swift') })
        """
```

with this script

```
let scriptSource = """
        document.getElementByClassName('carousel-container').addEventListener('touchstart', function() { console.log('touchstart from Swift') })
        """
```

But this time it was not working too. And question remains the same.